# Making PropertyValue of VertexLabels respect the order of VertexList (Graphs)

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Consider the following graph:

```
Clear[a, b, c]
graph = Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, 
  VertexLabels -> {b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 3}]
```

However

```
PropertyValue[graph, VertexLabels]

produces

{a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}
```

Which is not consistent with the order of

```
VertexList[graph]
```

which produces

```
{b, a, c}
```

I use the following to extract the vertex labels from a graph:

```
vertexLabels[g_] := #[[2]] & /@ PropertyValue[g, VertexLabels]
```

This does not produce the label list in an order that is consistent with VertexList.

The result is:

```
{1, 3, 2}
```

Rather than

```
{2, 1, 3}
```

Which would follow the order of vertices in VertexList[g]

Is there a way to address this?

And is there a reason why PropertyValue does not follow the VertexList order consistently?

I tried

```
Clear[a, b, c]
graph = Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, 
  VertexLabels -> {b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 3}]
```

I assumed that by adjusting the VertexLabels, so their assignment follows the vertex order of VertexList (first b, then a, then c), the result of PropertyValue would be match the order of VertexList.

This is not the case.

The code produces:

```
{a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}
```

as before.

I could adapt the code to reorganise the output to match the order of VertexList.

Is there another way to ensure this?

Comment: `PropertyValue[{graph, #}, VertexLabels] & /@ VertexList[graph1]`?

Comment: Great. Odd that PropertyValue picks a different order.

Comment: Weird indeed. You get  `{a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}` regardless of the order you specify the weights `PropertyValue[Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]`. This is so even if you specify the vertex list in the first argument of `Graph`: `PropertyValue[Graph[{a, b, c}, {b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]`

Comment: ... also regardless of the order  the edges are given: `PropertyValue[Graph[Reverse@{b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A work-around:**

First a simple fix to get what you need:

```
graph = Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> {b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 3}];

PropertyValue[{graph, #}, VertexLabels] & /@ VertexList[graph]
```

> ```
> {2, 1, 3}
> ```

```
VertexList[graph]
```

> ```
>   {b, a, c}
> ```

If you need list of rules:

```
Thread[VertexList[graph] -> (PropertyValue[{graph, #}, VertexLabels] & /@ 
    VertexList[graph])]
```

> ```
>  {b -> 2, a -> 1, c -> 3}
> ```

We get the same result (1) regardless of the order vertex labels are given, (2) regardless of the order edges are input, (3) regardless of whether a vertex list is specified in the first argument of `Graph` and (4) regardless of whether we use `PropertyValue` or `AnnotationValue`:

```
PropertyValue[Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]

PropertyValue[Graph[Reverse@{b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]

PropertyValue[Graph[{a, b, c}, {b -> a, a -> c}, VertexLabels -> #], 
   VertexLabels] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]
```

(and same lines with `PropertyValue` replaced with `AnnotationValue`) all give

> ```
> {{a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}, {a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}, {a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}, 
>   {a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}, {a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}, {a -> 1, c -> 3, b -> 2}}
> ```

**Note:** This also happens with `VertexShapeFunction`:

```
PropertyValue[Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, 
  VertexShapeFunction -> {b -> "Square", a -> "Star", c -> "Triangle"}], 
 VertexShapeFunction]
```

> ```
> {b -> "Square", c -> "Triangle", a -> "Star"}
> ```

We get the same result for all the variations above.

However, it does not happen with other properties like `VertexShape` or `VertexStyle`.

***What is going on?***

The source of the mysterious ordering `{a, c, b}` ***seems*** to be the ordering of vertices in *sorted* edge list of the input graph:

```
VertexList[Sort[EdgeList[Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, 
  VertexLabels -> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]] ]]
```

> ```
>  {a, c, b}
> ```

We get `{a, c, b}` for all the combinations explored below:

```
VertexList[Sort[EdgeList[Graph[{b -> a, a -> c}, 
    VertexLabels -> #]] ]] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]

VertexList[Sort[EdgeList[Graph[Reverse@{b -> a, a -> c}, 
    VertexLabels -> #]] ]] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]

VertexList[Sort[EdgeList[Graph[{a, b, c}, {b -> a, a -> c}, 
    VertexLabels -> #]] ]] & /@ Permutations[{a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]

VertexList[Sort[EdgeList[Graph[#, {b -> a, a -> c}, 
    VertexLabels -> {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3}]] ]] & /@ Permutations[{a, b, c}]
```

Comment: + thanks for the list of rules comment. Would love to know what goes on internally. It is as if PropertyValue/AnnotationValue performs a sort internally, fixing matters in a specific order. None that looks familiar though.